# erase entire C++ vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, erase

I would like to know which of the following version is the more appropriate to empty a `vector`, or if there is even a better way:

```
std::vector<T> v;
// 1
v.erase(v.begin(), v.end());
// 2
v = {};
```

My thought is that one has a complexity greater than the other, but one saves memory reallocation...

Comment: That depends whether you want to use the vector afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None. The idiomatic way is to call [`clear();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear):

```
std::vector<T> v = { ... };
v.clear();
```

Comment: I must have escaped it from the documentation...